# How to connect output port to input port

Tags: vhdl

In the top module two inputs are there `i1(3 downto 0)` and `i2(3 downto 0)` which is going to lower component and from this it is again going to another lower component.  After having some operation we are getting output in `data_o(3 downto 0)` from a memory unit.  Now my question is how to connect this `data_o` to `i2` so that next time we will feed only one input i.e `i1`.  The `i2` value will be taken as previous state `data_o` value, and iterate with this data.

I have written this code in VHDL:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;


entity top_Module is
  port (
    i1 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    i2 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    f1 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    f2 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    f3 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    f4 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

    start : in std_logic;
    ctrl  : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    sel   : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    clk   : in std_logic;

    address : in integer;
    rst     : in std_logic;

    --two main output.
    data_o : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    ca   : out std_logic;

    --fault indication.
    d_err      : out std_logic;
    cid_0      : out std_logic;
    cid_1      : out std_logic
    );
end top_Module;


architecture error_free of top_Module is

  component TMR_Module
    port (
      i1 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      i2 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      f1 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      f2 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      f3 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

      start : in  std_logic;
      ctrl  : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      sel   : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
      clk   : in  std_logic;
      --two main output y and ca;
      y     : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      ca  : out std_logic;

      d_err : out std_logic;
      cid_0 : out std_logic;
      cid_1 : out std_logic);
  end component;

  type ram_t is array (0 to 255) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal z    : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal z1   : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal ram  : ram_t := (others => (others => '0'));

begin

  x1 : TMR_Module port map(i1,
                           i2,
                           f1,
                           f2,
                           f3,
                           start,
                           ctrl,
                           sel,
                           clk,
                           z,
                           ca,
                           d_err,
                           cid_0,
                           cid_1
                           );

  process(Clk)
    variable data_i : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    variable i      :std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  begin
    z1         <= z or f4;
    if(rst = '1') then
      data_o <= ram(address);
    elsif(rising_edge(Clk))then
      if(f4 = "0000") then
        data_i       := z1;
        ram(address) <= data_i;
        i            := ram(address);
      else
        i := ram(address);
      end if;
      data_o <= i;
    end if;
  end process;

end error_free;
```

Now how to assign `data_o` or `ram(address)` value to `i2` so that next time I can give `i1` input only and `data_o` will be produced from `i1` and `i2 <= data_o`.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is to loop the ´data_o´ back to `i2` outside the
`top_Module`, whereby it is not required to do any modifications to the
`top_Module` itself, if the `top_Module` is not the final top.

Then code for this can be like:

```
i2_or_data <= i2 when (use_i2_not_data = '1') else data_o;
```

The `i2_or_data` is then a new signal that is connected to the `i2` port on
`top_Module`, and the `use_i2_not_data` is a new signal that controls if the
original `i2` or `data_o` is used in the iteration.

If `top_Module` is the final top in the device, then the selection between `i2`
`data_o` can be done inside the `top_Module` itself.  The code for this may be:

```
  -- Signals for selection between i2 and data_o as i2 port for TMR_Module
  signal data_o_sig      : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  -- Internal signal for internal use also
  signal use_i2_not_data : std_logic;                     -- Select between i2 ('1') or data_o ('0')
  signal i2_or_data      : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  -- i2 or data_o value

begin

  i2_or_data <= i2 when (use_i2_not_data = '1') else data_o_sig;

  x1 : TMR_Module port map(i1,
                           i2_or_data,
  ...
                           );

  process(Clk)
    variable data_i : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  begin
    z1         <= z or f4;
    d_err_buff <= z1(0) and z1(1) and z1(2) and z1(3);
    if(rst = '1') then
      data_o_sig <= ram(address);  -- Drive internal data_o_sig to allow internal use
    elsif(rising_edge(Clk))then
      if(f4 = "0000") then
        data_i       := z1;
        ram(address) <= data_i;
        i            <= ram(address);
      else
        i <= ram(address);
      end if;
      data_o_sig <= i;  -- Drive internal data_o_sig to allow internal use
    end if;
  end process;

  data_o <= data_o_sig;  -- Drive output port from internal signal
  ...
```

The internal `data_o_sig` is required for use of VHDL-2002 and earlier, since 
output ports can then not be read in a module.

In addition to the above, then the control signal `use_i2_not_data` must be
driven with the condition for using either `i2` or `data_o`.

Comment: please tell me what do u mean by outside "top_module"?is it mean that i have to create another module siting top of the "top_module"?can u please  elaborate the code in more detail?

Comment: @Ramakanta Chandra: Please find updated version that has the selection internally in the module.

Comment: thanks for ur kind reply.but that is not the output what i want.i am new in stackoverflow so i can't post the output image of the program (after modification).will u be kind enough to give me ur mail id.so that i can mail u what i really want.thank you.